# Recording conversation using Lync SDK 2013 in UI suppression mode

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I know i can save my conversation from the Lync Client (see [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/lync-help/record-and-play-back-a-lync-meeting-HA102809287.aspx)),

But can i save it from Lync SDK i am looking for method that simulate the Start Recording button in Lync client i am looking for something like this code:

```
conversation.BeginStartRecord();
```

or at least configure the server to automatically record any meeting?

In Streaming servers the streaming can sutomaticaly saved into the streaming server, so what is the case with Lync?

Did anyone go throw this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally find the answer in microsoft forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3d42342f-5d51-4d07-9454-79b386d7925d/lync-sdk-2013-recording-conversation-on-server?forum=communicatorsdk#3d42342f-5d51-4d07-9454-79b386d7925d):

> You cannot record with the Lync SDK, but you can record calls from a
>   UCMA endpoint. You can create a conference that includes the UCMA
>   endpoint and the other Lync clients, and then record the conference
>   with the UCMA endpoint.

So the answer is no can't record all the conversation (audio and video), their is a work around using UCMA endpoint to record audio only.
I think they should add this feature to the SDK.

**Update**

if anyone have same issue please vote by adding a comment in microsoft lync forum [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3d42342f-5d51-4d07-9454-79b386d7925d/lync-sdk-2013-recording-conversation-on-server?forum=communicatorsdk#1e1761c9-c078-4ab9-8a5d-be4b9c0019e6) to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Recorder (QuickStart)
Prerequisites
Microsoft Lync Server 2013.
One user capable of sending and receiving audio calls.
The credentials for the user, and a client capable of signing in to Lync Server 2013.
A client signed in to Lync Server 2013.

Only still audio calls are capable of being recorded?
because i see in code:

```
 using Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration.AudioVideo;
```

or

```
   // Create AudioVideoFlow
    AudioVideoFlowHelper audioVideoFlowHelper = new AudioVideoFlowHelper();
    _audioVideoFlow = audioVideoFlowHelper.CreateAudioVideoFlow(
        null,
        audioVideoFlow_StateChanged);
```

Answer (score -2):

You must handle it in the async way that's mean you should use `BeginStartRecord();` and `EndStartRecord();`

Comment: thanks Mohammad i can't find such method in lync documentation  is this doable? can you share some link to the documentation?

Comment: their is no BeginStartRecord BeginEndRecord functions i am suggesting such methods, this can't be an answer